# Reuse methods in Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin

I need to open one activity from several different points in the app. Let's say from Settings fragment, Main Activity and Navigation drawer (fragment). I don't want to copy/paste the same method and the method is very specific, it should be exactly the same (because it registeres Firebase events). How to structure the code in effective way? Where to put this method? One idea is to have a global ActivityUtils.kt file with just methods and it would be used to store these methods. I'm interested in the alternatives and what are pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a `companion object` in the Activity you need to open:

```
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun start(ctx: Context) {
            // put your logic here (registering of Firebase events)

            val i = Intent(ctx, YourActivity::class.java)
            ctx.startActivity(i)
         }
    }
}
```

And call it from another activity:

```
YourActivity.start(this)
```

or from another fragment:

```
YourActivity.start(context)
```

Comment: I like this approach because it keeps the code organized and one knows where to search for methods

Answer (score 0):

Use an extension method:

```
fun Activity.doMyStuff() {}
```

That can be called from any class extending Activity:

```
doMyStuff()
```

Extension functions like this shouldn't go inside a class, but rather inside a file. So if you were to make an `ActivityUtils.kt` file, don't have any sort of `class ActivityUtils {}` stuff in it. The function(s) should just go directly into the file.

Comment: then all activities would have access to this method. Wouldn't it create a mess?

Comment: Why would it "create a mess"? It's one method.

Comment: There will be way more than one method, just way a year or two:)

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use MVP?
Like,

```
interface IView { 
    val context: Context 
}

interface IPresenter { 
    fun launchActivity(view: IView) 
}

class MyActivityModel
{
    var key = "key"
    /*some other data*/

    fun getParcelableObject(): Parcelable
    {
        return /*some parcelable from model data*/
    }
}

class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity(), IView
{
    override val context: Context
        get() = this
}

class MyActivityPresenter() : IPresenter
{
    private var model: MyActivityModel = MyActivityModel()

    override fun launchActivity(view: IView)
    {
        val intent = Intent(view.context, MyActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(model.key, model.getParcelableObject())
        view.context.startActivity(intent)
    }

    fun setSomeDataToModel(someData: Any) {

    }
}

/*Everyone who wants to use presenter, must be a Context and implement IView*/
fun use()//in some fragment, or activity implementing IView
{
    MyActivityPresenter().launchActivity(this)
    //or
    val presenter = MyActivityPresenter()
    presenter.setSomeDataToModel("some data")
    presenter.launchActivity(this)
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I have more than 2 of these stacks View/Model/Presenter and in all of them I want to call the same method. So I wanted to avoid the copy/paste

Comment: The main idea is every activity has its own presenter. This own presenter knows how to start its activity only. So if activities/fragments A,B or C want to start activity D, they ask D's presenter to do this.
The main point is to remove any business logic from view(activity)

Comment: how will Views ABC ask presenter D to do work? then they need to create an instance of presenter D in themselves...this seems like the beginning of spaghetti code. But I agree with moving the business logic to the presenter.

Comment: Yes, but this will be a weak coupling, because the instance of D presenter will be created only in the place where ABC have to start activity. So it's either they know D activity(to use a static method), or D presenter. 
In my opinion, presenter looks more favorable, because probably you will have to pass some data to D, and if the call is in activity, the logic to create this data will bi in activity too, i.e., there will be copy/paste